# How does one compute the posterior odds ratio between two models

Tags: bayesian, posterior, odds-ratio

Apologies if this question has been asked before but I couldn't find anything that matched my problem.

I have some astronomy based data sets and wish to find which of three models fits the data the best. To do this I wish to compute the posterior odds ratios between each of the models. 
I know:
$$O_{1,2} = \frac{P(M_1|d)}{P(M_2|d)} = \frac{P(M_1)P(d|M_1)}{P(M_2)P(d|M_2)}$$

I predict that my three models are all equally likely so: 
$$O_{1,2} = \frac{P(d|M_1)}{P(d|M_2)}$$

For my first two models the odds ratio would then be:
$$O_{1,2} = \frac{\int_0^{10}P(d|x,M_1)P(x,M_1)dx}{P(d|M_0)P(M_0)}$$

Supposing this is correct so far, my question is then how to I determine $P(x, M_1)$? I know already that $P(M_0) = 1/3$ from the equal probability of each model. I am using a uniform prior on $x$ between 0 and 10 hence the limits on the integral so does that make $P(x, M_1) = 1/10$? I cant really see any way to argue for or against that.

I have written a short piece of code to take the product of $$O_{1,2} = \frac{\int_0^{10}P(d|x,M_1)\frac{1}{10}dx}{P(d|M_0)\frac{1}{3}}$$ but it gives an incredibly large number which does not seem correct.

I was wondering if I possibly need to take the integral of the sum of instead of the sum of the integral but again could not see any logic for this. The extremly large value suggests to me that one of the scaling/normalization factors I am using is wrong. Its possible that the way I am combining my model with a Gaussian for the noise is wrong however I was hoping someone could point out a hole in my logic above. Thanks in advance!